# mysql UPDATE multiple rows but single column different value fetch from array

Tags: php, mysql

ok so i have a php array it looks like

`array('somehash' => 'someotherhash', 'somehash2' => 'someotherhash2');`

here somehash = producthash and someotherhash = tohash

```
$db->query('UPDATE sometable SET status = '.self::STATUS_NOT_AVAILABLE.', towhere = '.self::TO_WHERE.', '.
                    .'tohash = WHEN or IF or ??? and how ?, '.
                    .'WHERE status = '.self::STATUS_AVAILABLE.'  AND '.
                    .'producthash IN (' . implode(',' , $prodarray) . ')') or $db->err(__FILE__,__LINE__);
```

so in the above query i want `tohash` value to be fetched from the php array via `producthash` mysql field

something like `tohash = IF(producthash IN '.$prodarray.', $prodarray['producthash'] , whatever)`

ofcourse the above IF wont work cause i dont have the producthash value in `$prodarray['producthash']`

anyone knows a way around this because i have more than 1000 values in the array and dont want to run thousand updates

the INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY is not possible in this cause because this table unique key is based on 3 fields and i dont have all the three field values while doing this update.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery?

```
UPDATE ...
WHERE ... producthash in (SELECT * FROM products)
```

This will work as long as you're not selecting from the same table you're updating - mysql doesn't allow that without workarounds.